# Workbook event in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, events

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If Weekday(Now) = vbSaturday Then
        Msg = "Today is SAturday, make sure that you "
        Msg = Msg & "submit the TPS report"
        MsgBox Msg
    End If

End Sub
```

The above code works when I press F5 but doesn't execute when I open the file.

1. Checked if code is placed at workbook level
2. Check application.enableevents=True

This has been frying my brain

Comment: It is working without any issue when I open the workbook.

Comment: Is the code in `Thisworkbook` ?

Comment: "Office Space" :) Check macro options. Maybe, there is something in **Trust Center**.